# How to validate if Log4Shell patch is applied?

Tags: vulnerability, java, log4shell

1. Is it enough to upgrade `log4j-core` and `log4j-api` to 2.15.0 but leave `log4j-slf4j-impl`, which is a binding library, to 2.14.1, given that `mvn dependency:tree` suggests that `log4j-slf4j-impl:2.14.1` is depending on `log4j-core:2.15.0` and `log4j-api:2.15.0` and the logging works appropriately? I am asking this because at the moment of havoc yesterday, `log4j-slf4j-impl` still haven't had `2.15.0` released.
2. Has the fix in 2.15.0 included a change to `LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS` being set to `true`? Running the following unit test suggests that the variable is still `false` with all of the dependencies in the 1st question being set to version `2.15.0`:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil;

@Test
public void testLog4j() {
    PropertiesUtil props = PropertiesUtil.getProperties();
    boolean val = props.getBooleanProperty("LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS");
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was: [Log4j2 no longer formats lookups in messages by default](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commit/04637dd9102175f765cfad349de0c2a63c279ac3#diff-aa430f3c17edcd69132aca6678db2439c8c078ccb99e835bbdbf25d448169bf6)

log4j-slf4j-impl doesn't include the vulnerable code so should be fine but is now updated to 2.15.0.

The `LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS` doesn't exist in your test so it's returning false but that's not how it's being read within log4j. The property is now being read as `PropertiesUtil.getProperties().getBooleanProperty("log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups", true)` so if it doesn't exist, then it'll default to true. This can be checked via:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Constants;
...
System.out.println(Constants.FORMAT_MESSAGES_PATTERN_DISABLE_LOOKUPS);
```

In the new version, this is true but also not used. Instead lookups have to be enabled via a pattern containing `%msg{lookups}`

The test from [MessagePatternConverterTest](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/04637dd9102175f765cfad349de0c2a63c279ac3/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/MessagePatternConverterTest.java) should show whether the lookups are happening:

```
@Test
public void testDisabledLookup() {
    final Configuration config = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder()
            .addProperty("foo", "bar")
            .build(true);
    final MessagePatternConverter converter = MessagePatternConverter.newInstance(
            config, new String[] {"nolookups"});
    final Message msg = new ParameterizedMessage("${foo}");
    final LogEvent event = Log4jLogEvent.newBuilder() //
            .setLoggerName("MyLogger") //
            .setLevel(Level.DEBUG) //
            .setMessage(msg).build();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    converter.format(event, sb);
    assertEquals("${foo}", sb.toString(), "Expected the raw pattern string without lookup");
}
```